# зачем прописывается селектор блока, если можно обойдись селектором элементом

Tags: css

```html
<!-- Block-1 -->
.logo .logo__img {
    display: block;
}

.logo .logo__text {
    color: #fff;
}


<!-- Block-2 -->
.logo__img {
    display: block;
}

.logo__text {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: можете не прописывать селектор блока, в чем проблема) но если встретится еще где-то(вне .logo) элемент с классом logo__image или logo__text то стили будут распространятся и на них.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я и так не прописываю их) Просто часто вижу в коде такое явление, вот и хотел узнать важно ли это.

Comment: .logo .logo__text это локально, а logo__text это глобально)

Comment: Для удобства, либо последствия компиляции [SCSS\SASS](https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/rasshirenie_css/vlozhennie_pravila/)